# Gradle dependencies in Idea project

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to use Gradle, but Idea dont see dependices. Here is my build.gradle

```
    group 'me.ozka'
    version '1.0.1'

    buildscript {
       ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.3'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

       }
    }

   apply plugin: 'java'
   apply plugin: 'kotlin'


   sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.20'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.0.0.RC2'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:9.0.0.RC2'

}
```

When i'm trying import *import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;* Idea signal me an error. What i'm doing wrong?

upd: i'm also don't see jar files in Idea External library folder.

**upd2:** i'm add to build file *apply plugin: 'jetty'* and it's solve my problem!

Comment: Did you try to run the Gradle task that downloads the dependencies?

Comment: What task you mean?

Comment: `build` should try to download all the dependencies and compile your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refresh your gradle dependencies.

Here are some ways of doing this.

#### Approach 1 (GUI):

- Go to `View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle`
- Click on the big refresh button (Refresh all gradle projects).

#### Approach 2 (Command):

`gradle build --refresh-dependencies`